# Railo 4.1.1 - How to Remove "exception-message" header

Tags: http-headers, tomcat7, railo

I'm failing a PCI compliance scan because my Railo server is **revealing the path to the document web root in an "exception-message" header** when a missing page is requested. 
 I tried using both the built-in Railo 404 template and my own custom 404 template to no avail. Is there anyway to get rid of this header from the reponse?

```
$ curl -I http://mydomain.com/this-page-does-not-exist.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 22:46:20 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
exception-message: Page /this-page-does-not-exist.html [/var/www/html/this-page-does-not-exist.html] not found
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 44
Set-Cookie: CFID=31254774-4b81-470d-b0da-dfadd4585ce0;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 08-Jan-2044 06:37:50 GMT
Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=0;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 08-Jan-2044 06:37:50 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: Looks like you've got Tomcat listening to port 80, yes? You can control how Tomcat responds with Tomcat's web.xml file.... maybe setting the displaySourceFragment to false in the web.xml file? Just a guess though.

Comment: Hi Jordan. I tried setting displaySourceFragment to false but the header is still showing the webroot path. <init-param>
     <param-name>displaySourceFragment</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>

Comment: Okay, looking into this more on your behalf I see now that that param won't work because it's for the JSP servlet and not the default servlet (which handles HTML files). Looking through the documentation (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html), I don't see any parameters which allow you to configure the exception message response.

It might be worthwhile to post this same message to the Tomcat-Users mailing list and let the Tomcat developers know that Coyote is failing PCI compliance tests. If they cannot point you to a fix they will at least be aware that it's an issue.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I just posted the question to the Tomcat-Users mailing list.  Waiting for a response.

Comment: Here's one response I got from the Tomcat-Users mailing list: "A quick grep of the Tomcat 7 trunk code does not reveal the string 'exception-message' anywhere. I didn't see anything in the change log concerning this, either."

Answer (score 1):

**Update: I was able to fix this problem by overwriting the header.**

I created a custom 404 template and then set the Missing Template Error (404) option to point at it in the Railo administrator. Then I added this line of code to the top of the page which seems to overwrite the header with a blank string.

```
<cfset getPageContext().getResponse().setHeader("exception-message","")>
```

Note: Using the tag `<cfheader>` to do the same thing does not work.  I'm not sure why but the Java route seems to do the trick.